# How to fix angular lz-string no export member

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, angular11, npm-package

Error: node_modules/secure-ls/dist/secure-ls.d.ts:24:24 - error TS2694: Namespac                                                                                                                                                             e '"/home/priyadharshinip/tree/ev2/multitenant/ui/node_modules/lz-string/typings                                                                                                                                                             /lz-string"' has no exported member 'LZStringStatic'.

24     LZString: LZString.LZStringStatic;

After installing angular-tree-grid-5.0.2 version I am facing this error while compiling the code..I am using angular version 11. I tried by updating lz-string and secure-ls package but it didn't work..

I tried by updating lz-string and secure-ls package but it didn't work..